# Binding a button action to a Child ViewModel with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

This should be easy, but its not working for me.  I have a view called MainWindowView that contains a view called ChildView.  The MainWindowView has a corresponding ViewModel called MainWindowViewModel and the ChildView has a ViewModel called ChildViewModel:

MainWindowView:

```
<Grid>
    <views:ChildView x:Name="ChildView"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    ChildView = new ChildViewModel();
}
```

ChildView:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Edit" x:Name="Edit"/> 
</Grid>
```

ChildViewModel:

```
public class ChildViewModel
{
    public void Edit()
    {

    }

    public ChildViewModel()
    {

    }
```

EDIT:

AppBootstrapper:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer container;

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new SimpleContainer();

        container.Instance(container);

        container
            .Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>()
            .Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

        container.PerRequest<MainWindowViewModel>();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<MainWindowViewModel>();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return container.GetInstance(service, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        container.BuildUp(instance);
    }

    protected override void OnUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "An error as occurred", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

and I might add that the views are in a root level Views folder and the view models are in a root level ViewModels folder.  Why won't the Edit command fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the MainWindowView to

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="ChildView" />
</Grid>
```

Somehow Caliburn.Micro was not able to bind the ChildView to its ViewModel properly.  I was confused because the ChildViewModel constructor was being called.  I guess that Caliburn.Micro knows how to bind the ContentControl, but not my custom view.

Comment: that was where I was going next. Correct it knows ContentControl and since contentcontrol can take any type by setting name to your Variable in the VM associated with the ChildVM, CM knows to place your "View" into that ContentControl.  Remember ViewModel First unless you want to make the switch over to View First but it takes placing bindings in the page declaration. `<Page cm.Model = "{Binding etc}" />` if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks that helps!

Answer (score 0):

well I am gonna go our on a limb and say that from my experience with CM and say that from what you have a shown there is probably a binding error.  What is supposed to happen?  Keep in mind CM is not view first out of the box with WPF.  Can you show us your bootstrapper?

Comment: Added bootstrapper.  I am getting a binding error, but it makes no sense to me: `Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'XNameTest.ViewModels.ChildViewModel' and 'System.Windows.Visibility'.`

Comment: it doesn't understand (CM) how to convert the bindings for your `<views:ChildView x:Name="ChildView"/>` so it throws the binding error.